# spring.jackson properties not found

Tags: serialization, spring-boot, jackson, jodatime

In my Spring Boot project it seems none of the spring.jackson properties are working. I want to take controll over date fields and I tried to add the following properties to my application.properties file:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
spring.jackson.joda-date-time-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Dates still come as timestamps (java.util.Date and joda.time). I have the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I didn't add version number but it says the managed version number is 2.8.7 (with all three).

I've read if I use `@EnableWebMvc` annotation on any class, it won't work. But I don't use such annotation. (However I have spring-webmvc on my classpath.)
When I start the application (in Tomcat), I got these log messages:

```
2017-04-23 16:54:55 DEBUG JndiTemplate:150 - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS]
2017-04-23 16:54:55 DEBUG JndiLocatorDelegate:101 - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS] not found - trying original name [spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS].
2017-04-23 16:54:55 DEBUG JndiTemplate:150 - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS]
2017-04-23 16:54:55 DEBUG JndiPropertySource:99 - JNDI lookup for name [spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS].. Returning null.
2017-04-23 16:54:55 DEBUG PropertySourcesPropertyResolver:151 - Found key 'spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS' in [URL [file:C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 9.0/conf/Catalina/localhost/Blowfish/config/application.properties]] with type [String]
```

Only one thing worked with both java.util.Date and joda.time:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) { 
        for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
            if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter;
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = jsonMessageConverter.getObjectMapper();
                objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't like this solution, it would be more elegant to use some configuriation in my application.properties.

I use Spring Boot 1.5.2.

Comment: That will only work if you aren't messing around with an object mapper or other Jackson settings yourself. So without seeing your configuration it is hard to tell.

Comment: I don't have any jackson configuration. However, I have a static object which I use to convert objects to another, because I need to cast some object coming from json. 

    `public static Object convertValue(Object object, Class clazz)
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      return mapper.convertValue(object, clazz);
    }`

But after eliminating this, the problem still comes.